# Verify all the options of a drop down in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am writing selenium webdriver code in c#. I want to verify all the options of a drop down. I am using the following code. But its giving me an error for 'soc.options.text'. May I know where I am getting wrong?

```
SelectElement soc = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("soc_id_look")));
string[] drop = { "x----x", "Ra", "Ma", "sa", "ga", "ta" };
string[] actual = soc.Options.Text;
int n = drop.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
Console.Write(" " + drop[i]);
Assert.IsTrue(drop[i].Equals(actual[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I guess you are getting an error because `soc.Options` will return a **collection** of `IWebElement`'s, and therefore `.Text` is not accessible.

Regardless of the error you are getting, the `for` loop can be condensed into a single LINQ statement:

```
Assert.IsTrue(drop.All(d => actual.Contains(d)));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

So it translates into "does every element within the "drop" array exist within the "actual" array? If so, return true, otherwise return false.

Now, to fix the inital error you were getting, you can, again, use LINQ, to translate it into a collection of `string`'s:

```
IEnumerable<string> actual = soc.Options.Select(i => i.Text);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

So this would become "take each `IWebElement` within this collection, get the value of it's `.Text` property and return that." So we'd end up with a collection of `string`'s.

We put it all together and end up with:

```
SelectElement soc = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("soc_id_look")));
string[] drop = { "x----x", "Ra", "Ma", "sa", "ga", "ta" };
IEnumerable<string> actual = soc.Options.Select(i => i.Text);
Assert.IsTrue(drop.All(d => actual.Contains(d)));
```

However, just as a note, if you get errors (whether compiler or runtime) you should post the **entire** error, along with the **entire** stack trace (if there is one). It is near impossible to help when someone says "I get an error" and we've got no idea **whatsoever** on what error it is. Just a friendly tip to help you get the best out of StackOverflow.

I can guess the error you got was probably something along the lines of `IEnumerable<IWebElement> does not contain a definition for ".Text"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
IList<IWebElement> options = soc.Options;

Assert.Equals(options.Count, drop.Length);

foreach (IWebElelent option in options)
{
    Console.Write(" " + drop[i]);
    Assert.IsTrue(drop.Contains(option.Text));
}
```